# Refresh token not coming with authorize endpoint in oauth2

Tags: spring, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get refresh token when authorizing the user.

This is the url that is being used for authorization.

**request**

```
https://...../oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=test-client&scope=all&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:7002%2F...%2Foauth
```

**redirect url with token and etc :**

```
https://localhost:7002/..../oauth#access_token=b3961289-713c-41c9-9341-253286cbcc52&token_type=bearer&expires_in=300&scope=all
```

but there isn't any refresh token with this. I tried this with token endpont and it has the refresh token like this

**request**

```
curl --data 'grant_type=password&username=....&password=...' --basic --user 'test-client:client-secret' 'https://....../oauth2/token'
```

**response**

```
{  
   "scope":"all",
   "access_token":"5a90edb7-5ded-451a-9d9b-d3bd879ac336",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "expires_in":300,
   "refresh_token":"ec0c94db-5e81-4229-a815-9c2d80086995"
}
```

Is there anyway that I can get refresh token in authorization endpoint. ? Or 
can I use existing token to get refresh token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got to long for a comment

It kind of depends upon the authentication server how it works.  Some servers only return a refresh token the first time the user authenticates.

To get a Refresh Token, you must include the offline_access scope when you initiate an authentication request through the authorize endpoint.

For example, if you are using Authorization Code Grant, the authentication request would look like the following:

```
https://__AUTH0_NAMESPACE__/authorize?
    audience={API_AUDIENCE}&
    scope=offline_access&
    response_type=code&
    client_id=__AUTH0_CLIENT_ID__&
    redirect_uri=__AUTH0_CALLBACK__&
    state={OPAQUE_VALUE}
```

This is the only way to obtain a refresh token so no you cant use another token to request get a refresh token.

**Implicit client**

In the implicit grant flow, the client is requesting access to a resource by way of a "User Agent", aka browser with the user sitting there. So a client wants to grab something, but needs the user to enter permissions for it.  If the authentication server provided a refresh token, then the client could skip asking the user for permission in the future and grant itself access forever (essentially refreshing its token whenever it wants without user permission). This is forbidden in the flow because the "untrusted" client should only have access by way of having the user enter their credentials (thus only when the resource owner allows it).

Comment: I have implemented single sign on through redirection. I used Implicit Grant not Authorization code Grant. Now I understood why they don't  provide the refresh token with authorization. I think that, It should be secure because if it expose to outside, they can continuously refresh the token. so that it will never be expired. According to my requirement i have to use Implicit Grant.

Comment: for more information, I am using response_type=token.

Comment: IIR implicit clients dont normally return a refresh token.

Comment: Your explanation about implicit grant type is very understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a refresh token when using the Implicit grant.

I presume your application is a Single Page App? i.e. html/JavaScript running in a user's browser. This is the main use case for the Implicit grant nowadays.

If it's not a SPA (e.g. native, mobile or web application) you should be able to use a different grant type which will give you a refresh token. e.g. Authorisation Code Grant or Authorisation Code with PKCE Grant.